# Android Custom Asset Pixelated

Tags: android, android-studio, radio-button, assets

I've been trying to create an image button to use in my test app. Once I've imported the asset it looks grainy and pixelated, especially compared to the app_compat radio button. Here is the comparison (custom asset on left).

[image]

How can I get the edges of my custom asset to be as clean as the radio button?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide assets for various screen **densities**. If your app is not providing such assets directly, then Android will try to make such by usually scalling what your app provides. This usually ends with pixelated graphics. Please read this article about how all this work in Android: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I am aware of this. Would this affect the way it looks in the editor as well?

Comment: you mean editor in IDE? good question - I'd not care much there. If you provide assets in all supported densities correctly you should be fine. Definitely it's always important to design your assets in higher supported density and **downscale** later (or export if you do vectors). to avoid upscaling pixelation

Comment: Well I'm running all of this on a physical device as well. Where do I find the info for whether this device is hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi etc.?